# jQuery global selection "cache"

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I don't think I'm the first one to run into this issue but I haven't find a way to search for this without getting results that have nothing to do with the issue.

I adopted the not so extended good practice of "caching" repetitive jQuery selections into vars like `var element = $('#element');` to prevent "DOM pool searching" for every repeated use of the element

The problem I'm having is that now I'm doing this caching inside a function. Something like:

```
function functionname (id) {
    var id = $('#'+id);
    //extra stuff
}
```

I'm not expert in variables scopes but I'm not being able to do

```
functionname ('some-div-id');
some-div-id.dialog('open');
```

So I'm pretty sure it's because the variable created inside the function is not accesible outside the function itself.

Then I came up with

```
function functionname (id) {
        window.id = $('#'+id);
        //extra stuff
}
```

but if I try to do `window.some-div-id.dialog('open');` I get `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function`

What am I missing? I'm sure it's a small dumb thing but I'm missing it just in front of my eyes.

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone but you're missing something.
The code suggestions are missing the fact that the inside "global" variable name is dynamic:

var CACHEobject = {};

```
function doSomething (NAMEHERE) { //note the function parameter 
   CACHEobject.NAMEHERE = $('#'+NAMEHERE);
}
```

So the idea is that the function creates a javascript variable with the same name that the #element_id. If I pass a name to the function it should select the html id with that name and "cache it" to a global variable with the same name:

```
doSomething('myDialogOne'); doSomething('myDialogTwo');
```

so I can later do

```
CACHEobject.myDialogOne.dialog('open'); CACHEobject.myBox.dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want (based off the edit):

```
var CACHEobject = {};
function doSomething(id) { 
   CACHEobject[id] = $('#' + id);
}
```

Comment: FINALLY! I knew it wasn't that complicated, I was missing the [stuff]. Thanks @mikeycgto

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is fine. Just set up an object for that. Here's an example using `STASH` as the caching object:

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
var STASH = {};
$(document).ready(function(){

    // stash your elements
    STASH.item = $('#item');
    STASH.otherItem = $('#otherItem');


    // do stuff to them
    STASH.item.css({
        color: '#f00'
    }); // sets #item to red
    alert(STASH.otherItem.text()); // alerts foo
});
</script>
<style></style>
<body>
    <div id="item">bar</div>
    <div id="otherItem">foo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but in you code the cache var names are not dynamic inside the function. see my question edit please

Answer (score 0):

```
window.some-div-id.dialog('open');
```

is interpreted as:

```
window.some - div - id.dialog('open');
```

i.e. subtracting, which causes three undefined variables, one of which is `id.dialog` which causes an error when trying to be executed as a function.

For special characters, use:

```
window["some-div-id"].dialog('open');
```

And to define:

```
window[id] = $("#" + id);
```

Anyhow, I would not advise you to use global variables. You'd better overwrite the jQuery function to implement caching (using an object with the selector as key and the matched element as value).

Comment: I'm not using "-"s in the id names, I never do, I just put them for the example to be more readable

Comment: @Juan: I think you do want `window[id] = ...` instead of `window.id` though.

Comment: Thanks @pimvdb but still same issue: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window['mensajes'].dialog('open')')

Comment: @Juan: I'm not sure what exactly is causing that problem; this trivial example works: http://jsfiddle.net/zAgPY/.

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare the variable outside the function.

```
var $foo;

function some_function(id) {
  $foo = $('#' + id);
}
```

Comment: thanks but in you code the cache var names are not dynamic inside the function. see my question edit please.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setDialog(selector) {
    window.$dialogElem = $(selector);
    //window.dialogSelector = selector; 
}

var id= 'mensajes';
setDialog('#'+id);
window.$dialogElem.dialog();
//$(window.dialogSelector).dialog();
```

commented stuff is an alternative that takes less memory. But why the hell use window?? check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CnBJ/) for various simple techniques.